# .JSON file won't open properly

Tags: json

I've been trying to open these .json files but I keep getting this error code, when I open in NotePad, I get a bunch of raw data. How do I convert the raw data or open the file properly?

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

https://files.fm/u/vqravnyf

Comment: Hi, please describe about what tool or language did you use for loading json ?

Comment: Yes, I was sent some files, that were in .zip folder. The folder contained files in .json. I just clicked on them and some open in my browsers, the others showed the error code above. I'm afraid this is beyond my scope at the moment.

Comment: Are you able to open examSummary.json? The other files appear corrupted.

Comment: I am able to. Is there a reason why the others are corrupted? Could they possibly be encrypted?